# App crashes when rotating screen

Tags: android, kotlin, google-vision, vision-api

I am using Mobile Vision API to detect faces on front facing camera. I used Google's FaceTracker demo, but I need to use it in Fragment. It is working, but when I try to rotate screen, application crashes with exception `RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`.

Fragment code:

```
class EyeTrackerFragment : Fragment(), AnkoLogger {

private var cameraSource: CameraSource? = null

private lateinit var cameraSourcePreview: CameraSourcePreview
private lateinit var graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay

private var callback: OnEyeContextUpdatedListener? = null

companion object {
    // google play services error code
    private val RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001
    // permission request codes need to be < 256
    private val RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    try {
        callback = activity as OnEyeContextUpdatedListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException("${activity} must implement OnEyeContextUpdatedListener")
    }
}

/**
 * Restarts the camera.
 */
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    startCameraSource()
}

/**
 * Stops the camera.
 */
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    cameraSourcePreview.stop()
}

/**
 * Releases the resources associated with the camera source, the associated detector, and the
 * rest of the processing pipeline.
 */
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    cameraSource?.release()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_face_tracker, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    cameraSourcePreview = getView()!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.preview) as CameraSourcePreview
    graphicOverlay = getView()!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.faceOverlay) as GraphicOverlay

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.applicationContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        createCameraSource()
    } else {
        requestCameraPermission()
    }
}

/**
 * Handles the requesting of the camera permission.  This includes
 * showing a "Toast" message of why the permission is needed then
 * sending the request.
 */
private fun requestCameraPermission() {
    warn("Camera permission is not granted. Requesting permission")

    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM)
        return
    }

    Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, "Give me permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

private fun createCameraSource() {
    val detector = FaceDetector.Builder(context.applicationContext)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
            .build()

    val faceTracker = GraphicFaceTracker(graphicOverlay, callback, context)
    val faceProcessor = LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(detector, faceTracker)
    detector.setProcessor(faceProcessor)

    if (!detector.isOperational) {
        longToast("Face detector dependencies are not yet available.")
    }

    cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build()
}

private fun startCameraSource() {
    // check that the device has play services available.
    val code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
            context.applicationContext)
    if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        val dlg = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(activity, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS)
        dlg.show()
    }

    if (cameraSource != null) {
        try {
            cameraSourcePreview.start(cameraSource!!, graphicOverlay)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            error("Unable to start camera source.", e)
            cameraSource!!.release()
            cameraSource = null
        }

    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode != RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM) {
        debug("Got unexpected permission result: $requestCode")
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        return
    }

    if (grantResults.size != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        debug("Camera permission granted - initialize the camera source")
        createCameraSource()
        return
    }

    error("Permission not granted: results len = ${grantResults.size}. Result code = ${if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) grantResults[0] else "(empty)"}")

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setTitle("Face Tracker sample")
            .setMessage("Have no camera permission")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", { _, _ -> activity.finish() })
            .show()
}
```

}

According to Activity code. It only attaches previous fragment in onCreate method and then does not do anything.

I guess that camera instance was not released in some situation, but it is done in the same way like in Activity. Is there any special behavior in Fragment that would require extra actions in comparision with activies?

Full exception log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.eyetracker.android.demo, PID: 22631
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:520)
                  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:361)
                  at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.zzchq(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.start(Unknown Source)
                  at com.eyetracker.android.camera.CameraSourcePreview.startIfReady(CameraSourcePreview.kt:82)
                  at com.eyetracker.android.camera.CameraSourcePreview.access$startIfReady(CameraSourcePreview.kt:18)
                  at com.eyetracker.android.camera.CameraSourcePreview$SurfaceCallback.surfaceCreated(CameraSourcePreview.kt:104)
                  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:580)
                  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
                  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:948)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: please add your code and error log

Comment: did you try android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"?

Comment: How would that helped me?

Comment: it prevents activity from restart

Comment: Not really what I'd have wanted. I need to inflate new layout file in case of rotation.

Comment: Add the code for your Activity and Fragment as well. The most probable reason would be improper handling of activity recreation on orientation change.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar I added the source code

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Android destroys and recreates your Activity for orientation change, it calls onSaveInstanceState().

So do save necessary data in a Bundle in onSaveInstanceState() and restore the same in onCreate() by checking if field savedInstanceState is null?